# Which autoformatter to use for structurizr's DSL?

Tags: structurizr

[Structurizr](https://github.com/structurizr), a tool that is recommended to design a [c4model](https://c4model.com/), comes with its own [DSL](https://github.com/structurizr/dsl). It looks a bit like this:

```
workspace {

    model {
        user = person "User"
        softwareSystem = softwareSystem "Software System"

        user -> softwareSystem "Uses"
    }

    views {
        systemContext softwareSystem {
            include *
            autolayout
        }

        theme default
    }
    
}
```

I need a tool that would format this code automatically.